# Overwrite data in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

---

I try to make an storage where i can save my image in firebase storage but everytime i upload a new image it will replace the old one,i want evertime a new image will be save on storage,i am on android studio using kotlin,Is my code is wrong?here is my code

---

```
class Activity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

var curFile: Uri? = null
val imageRef = Firebase.storage.reference
private val userCollection = Firebase.firestore.collection("persons")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2)
    
    //here where a button to get an image from gallery
    tvpilihfoto.setOnClickListener {
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).also {
            it.type = "image/*"
              val REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_PICK = 0
                startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_PICK)
         }
    //this button for an upload activity to send the image to database firebase
    btnupload.setOnClickListener {
        uploadImageToStorage("my image")
    }
}

private fun uploadImageToStorage(filename : String) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        curFile?.let {
             imageRef.child("images/$filename").putFile(it).await()
              withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Toast.makeText(this@Activity2,"Foto anda telah dipilih",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    } catch (e : Exception) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(this@Activity2,e.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    val REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_PICK = 0
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_PICK) {
        data?.data?.let {
            curFile = it
            ivfoto.setImageURI(it) 
            //this where my image get or display in app
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are  you sure you are always using different names?

Comment: i try not to confused so i using all my layout to differen name,i will make more it clear by using Kotlin Comment //

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're always calling `uploadImageToStorage("my image")`, the image will alway be called `my image`. So each time you make that call, it will overwrite the previous `my image` in storage.

To always add a new image, generate a unique filename in your code. For example:

```
uploadImageToStorage(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
```